# JUnit Launcher test... getActivity is not return

Tags: android, junit

public class LauncherActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2< Launcher> {
    private Launcher mActivity;

```
public LauncherActivityTest() {
    super("com.android.launcher.Launcher", Launcher.class);
}

@Override
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    setActivityInitialTouchMode(true);
}

public void testLauncherApplication() {
    mActivity = getActivity();
    assertTrue(mActivity != null);
}
```

}

add....
manifest.xml
    < uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
    < instrumentation android:targetPackage="com.launcher.launcher"
                     android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner" />

I try to Launcher source test by JUnit.
Why getActivity() function is not return?
My Phone is only running Launcher. but other application running and then run test is well.

ex) phone app run -> test : return success
    only launcher running : wait state

Do you know why? Help me, please.

Answer (score 0):

Do u have in manifest file:

```
 <instrumentation
    android:targetPackage="com.android.example.spinner"
    android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner" />
```

And also check this:

```
public class LauncherActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<ActivityToTest>
```

Comment: I just want to make test program of Launcher like of SpinnerActivityTest. Doesn't try to debugging.

Comment: Its possible that u have a bug there and therefore an activity is not created.